# Which float switch to use for my A/C unit?

Tags: switches

[This](http://www.docs.hvacpartners.com/idc/groups/public/documents/techlit/ss-pf4m-02.pdf) is my A/C unit in the attic.

These are the two switches I've found.  But the specs don't really match up with that document.

[Switch 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012DK12Q)

I can't post 3 links due to lack of reputation but here are the specs for the other switch:

- 72-Inch lead wires
- 48 VAC/DC
- 5 Amps Auxiliary safety switch

How do I know what will work?

Comment: See my answer below. Please say what is being switched. Is it just the 40 VA fan load or heating as well? | You want a switch rated for AC at at least the mains voltage you are using and able to handle more VA or Watts than your load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a switch rated for AC at at least the mains voltage you are using and able to handle more VA or Watts than your load.

Temporary paragraph:
 Please say what is being switched.
 Is it just the 40 VA fan load or heating as well? |

---

The 48 VAC switch is almost certainly unsuitable - see below.

The switch you linked to (photo below) is rated at up to 230 VAC and at 11 Amps current.  It will work with AC voltages lower than 230 VAC as well.
 At 110 VAC a 11 A switch is rated at 11 x 110 =  1210 VA - say 1200 VA or 1200 Watts.
 At 230 VAC a 11 A switch is rated at 1about 2500 VA or Watts.

If you are in Texas then your mains may be 110 VAC unless you are operating betwen two transformer halves - but voltage wise it should be OK regardless.
 **The 11A raing may be too low** or very ample depending what you are switching.

The electrical rating of the [Payne PF4PMA](http://www.docs.hvacpartners.com/idc/groups/public/documents/techlit/ss-pf4m-02.pdf) that you refer to is shown as 40 VA. ie your 11A switch will handle it with ease.
 BUT there is also reference to a 3 to 30 kW heater. Your switch would die just looking at that load.
 (2500 VA is ALMOST 3000 Watts BUT you really want some safety factor. 30,000 Watts is "unusual" in a home installation).

[image]

IF the unlinked-to switch is switching a lower voltage load at the output of a transformer then it MAY be suitable. Voltage would need to be <= 48VAC and current <= 5A.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I guess I'd just need to switch the A/C component off. Though I'm not sure I can wire it such that I only turn that off.  The heater and fan don't need to be affected by this switch.

Answer (score 0):

Residential HVAC systems have a high voltage circuit and a low voltage circuit.  High voltage is used for the compressor, fans and heat strips or what not and the low voltage(created by a transformer in the air Handler) is for the control circuit.

The low voltage circuit is almost certainly 24VAC to 28VAC and 3A. (even though that PDF says the transformer is 40VAC they typically don't output that much.)

The 48 VAC/DC, 5 Amps Auxiliary safety switch will work and it will need to be wired in-line with the condenser(outside unit) thermostat wire at the air handler. Typically the yellow thermostat wire.

To make sure which color thermostat wire you should break with the switch, you can pop the cover off of the Thermostat and check to see what color T-stat wire is on the "Y" terminal.